# c++ program printing out address instead of value

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a program that takes in information through a struct and puts it into a vector, and I'm trying to print that information out but instead get an address. The structure should hold the values correctly so I think it's either my pointers or the way I'm printing it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
  char* fName;
  char* lName;
  int id;
  float gpa;
};

void add(vector<student*>*);

int main() 
{
  vector <student*>* list = new vector<student*>();


    if (strcmp(cmd,"ADD") == 0)
    {
      add(list);  
    }
    else if (strcmp(cmd,"PRINT") == 0)
    {
      for(vector<student*>::iterator i = list->begin(); i != list->end(); i++)
      {
        cout << *i;
      }
      cout << "print" << endl;
    }
}
  void add(vector<student*>* paramlist)
  {
    student* s = new student();
    s->fName = new char[25];
    s->lName = new char[25];

    cout << "Enter first name" << endl;
    cin >> s->fName;

    cout << "Enter last name" << endl;
    cin >> s->lName;

    cout << "Enter id number" << endl;
    cin >> s->id;

    cout << "Enter GPA" << endl;
    cin >> s->gpa;

    paramlist->push_back(s);
  }
```

Or it might have something to do with the way I iterate through the vector.

Comment: You may want to read this official help page for a possible explanation of why your question has received at least one downvote (not from me): [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why are you using pointers at all? You should simply use `std::vector<student>` instead of `std::vector<student*>*` and `std::string` instead of `char*`. This will immediately make your code simpler, safer, and free of memory leaks

Comment: a lot of extra new expression that shouldn't be there, this style produces memory leaks

Comment: @alterigel sorry it's for a school project, I have to use pointers.

Comment: @FaizanKarim `vector<student*>` spells disaster because that vector wouldn't free memory allocated for student, and apparently `student` doesn't deallocate strings. `void add(vector<student*>* paramlist)` isn't C++ way unless you require to operate on pointer,  would be `void add(vector<student*>& paramlist)`

Comment: @FaizanKarim I'm terribly sorry to hear that. Your school is teaching you terrible habits

Comment: @alterigel it may be an assignment to demonstrate why this is bad. I'm suspect it should be taught another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an operator overload for your struct, to define how the struct should appear when printed. You also need to dereference the pointer as well as the iterator.

```
// Define how the struct should look when printed.
// This function makes it appear like:
// Name: John Smith, ID: 1235, GPA: 4.0
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const student &val) {
  os
    << "Name: " << val.fname << " " << val.lname
    << ", ID: " << val.id
    << ", GPA: " << val.gpa
    << endl;

  return os;
}
```

Then later...

```
for(vector<student*>::iterator i = list->begin(); i != list->end(); i++)
{
  // Dereference twice, once for the iterator, and again for the pointer.
  cout << **i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to dereference twice `**i`.
With `*i` you get the address of vector<student*> element that is `student*`.
You get `student`, you need other `*`.

You may use `for (auto i: list)` to make your life easier.

Comment: The thing is if I put 2 ```*``` then i get an invalid operands to binary expression ostream and student .

Comment: You’re right about the solution. But `*i` does not give the address of the container element. It’s reference to the container element. And since the container here holds pointers, `*i` is a reference to a pointer.

Comment: @Faizan Karim, because you did not write `ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const student &val)`.